# Improve visibility and consistency of interest tagged questions?

Tags: feature-request

I can never remember how to get to the Stack Exchange page that shows a list of questions across all sites based on my favorite/interesting tags. I also wish it was easier to add tags as interesting either by some means such as clicking on the tag (in the list of tags in a question) and then being taken to a page where I can easily favorite the tag, or mousing over the tag and somehow favoriting it.

Essentially it'd allow me to build a custom/filtered "here are the topics I am most likely to be able to answer" page that I could easily check.  I also find it annoying that even when I do stumble upon my interesting questions page, it doesn't have all the sorting options usually available on other pages and the default sorting is also different.

Edit: Essentially I feel like alot could be done to pull these related features together under more consistent naming and make them more straightforward to access.  I would not have thought that I'd have to go to Hot Questions and then click filters.  On stackoverflow there's a "tag subscriptions" link on the right that takes you to essentially the same thing, but only for that site.

When you mouse over that star for a tag, it uses the terminology "Favorite" instead of "Interest".

If you are going to call them "Favorites" then use that terminology when you display links for filtering questions for these favorited tags.  I.e. somewhere near the tag cloud on the right or near the top to the left of the Quesiton sorting tabs put "Show only favorited tags".  Not tag "susbcriptions", or "filters".  Or if you prefer the term subscription, and want to leave the "Tag subscriptions" link as it is, then change the interested/favorite tags to be "subscribed tags" and label the option to favorite a tag as "subscribe" or "subscribe to tag".

Change the "Hot Questions" link on the Stackexchange front page to "Questions".  I don't care about Hotness and I wouldn't have thought to go through that link to get to what I wanted.  The page it links to gives the user the option to sort by Hotness if they want to.   So just call it "Questions" and let the user click the Hotness tab once they get to that page.

On stackoverflow, if you click **Unanswered question**, you have a **My Tags** option.  If you click **Questions** tab, there is **no My Tags** option.  If you go just to stackoverflow.com, you are presented with **Top Question** which has an **Interesting** tab.  I recommend standardizing the sort options available for these three different views, so that the landing page for stackoverflow's Top Questions, as well as Unanswered Questions, and All Questions, each have a sort tab to short questions for favorited tags and use the same Label/Naming for that tab.

Ideally it wouldn't really be a sort, but a "Show only favorites" option to the left of the sorting tabs(between the "All Questions" text on the left and sorting tabs on the right).  This would allow me to combine a sort with the Favorites filter.

Comment: What kind of sorting are you missing?

Comment: Just so I understand, we currently have 'subscribe' and 'rss' in the box you see when you hover over a tag. You'd also like a way to add that tag to your favorites (in the same place), which is automatically added to your filters on the interesting/hot questions list?

Comment: Just like on all Stack Exchange sites: for future posts one topic per question please.

Comment: @TimPost As Tom points out, I can just click the star.  I didn't reallize this.  IDK if maybe something can be done to make it more clear that I can click the star to actually do something.  From the screenshot it looks like there'd be room to move the "75 followers" to the bottom right, and add something more verbose, like "favorite | subscribe | rss" or put something next to the star that changes as you click saying "Click to Favorite"->"Click to Ignore" etc.

Comment: @AaronLS Don't feel too bad, I didn't know it did anything either. Then again, I have not changed any of my tag preferences in quite some time (or felt the need to).

Comment: @TimPost The more confusing thing is trying to get to the page where I see questions filtered based on these tags.  The naming conventions of links and the abscence of the option in certain contexts.  I have Edited to provide some specific examples.  It is a bit of rambling admittedly, but hopefully exemplifies the problem.

Answer (score 5):

On [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) hit `Hot Questions` and then `My Filters` to get to that page.

Try clicking the **star** in the pop-up that comes when hover your mouse over a tag.
That should add the tag to the `Favorite Tags` filter...

[image]

Comment: I think he wants to be able to tickle those filters (and tag favorites / ignores) from the fly out that comes up when you hover over a tag. Not sure, though.

Comment: @TimPost: Yeah, just wanted to note where he could find that. While it does answer the title of his question it isn't a full answer though. I think the **star** in that pop-up does what he want, could it be?

Comment: I never knew that star was anything other than an icon. I'll go iron my hands now. Yeah, if I understand his question correctly, it does what I think he wants :)